# What does 128M mean?

Tags: mysql, ram

Reading configuration files, like my.cf, I am seeing this:

> This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays

What does the `M` mean in general, and what kind of measurement unit is it in? Does it refer to a megabyte which has the value of 1024?

If a machine has 1 gigabyte of ram how much `M` is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`M` means `megabyte`.

> 1 T(terabyte) = 1024 gigabytes
>
> 1 G(gigabyte) = 1024 megabytes
>
> 1 M(megabyte) = 1024 kilobytes
>
> 1 K(kilobyte) = 1024 bytes

Comment: There's no such thing as 1KB, it's 1kB.

Comment: @TheBlueDog According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte, "The binary representation of 1024 bytes typically uses the symbol KB, using an upper-case K." It's not correct?

Comment: No, the abbreviation for kilo is lower case (k).

Answer (score 0):

1 byte (B) = 8 bits
1 KB = 1024 bytes = 2^10 bytes
1 MB = 2^10 KB = 2^20 bytes
1 GB = 2^10 MB = 2^30 bytes